# Truncated data (if more than 512 bytes) when using boost::asio::async_read_until from serial port

Tags: c++, windows, serial-port, boost-asio

I'm using the boost::asio::async_read_until function to read from a serial port in Windows 10. The delimiter is a Regex pattern. It works as expected as long as the data recieved is not larger than 512 bytes.

If the data received is larger than 512 bytes, it is simply truncated and the "readComplete" function will not be called again. However if I send more data, 1 byte is enough, the missing data is received together with the new data.

I have used the same implementation on a tcp/socket and that works flawlessly. Is there any limit in the native serial interface in Windows causing this behaviour?

EDIT 1: I have noted that if the baud rate is lowered from 115200 to 28800 no data is missing.

```
// from .h-file: boost::asio::streambuf streamBuf_;

void RS232Instrument::readAsyncChars()
{
   boost::asio::async_read_until(
      serial_,
      streamBuf_,
      boost::regex(regexStr_.substr(6, regexStr_.length() - 7)),
      boost::bind(
         &RS232Instrument::readComplete,
         this,
         boost::asio::placeholders::error,
         boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void RS232Instrument::readComplete(const boost::system::error_code& error, size_t bytes_transferred)
{   
   if(error)
   {
     // Error handling
   }
   else
   {
      std::string rawStr(
         boost::asio::buffers_begin(streamBuf_.data()),
         boost::asio::buffers_begin(streamBuf_.data()) + bytes_transferred);

      // Log the data in rawStr....

      // Remove data from beginning until all data sent to log
      streamBuf_.consume(bytes_transferred);

      if(abort_ == false)
      {
         readAsyncChars();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have found out was caused this problem I'll answer the question myself.

I had left out some code above for the sake of clarity, code which I did not realise was actually the problem.
Example of code left out:

LOG_DEBUG("Rs232Data received");

I use the boost:log functionality and I have added more "sinks" to the the log framework. The sink used in this case logs to a vector in ram and prints to console when triggered from user input.

It turns out that the log framework consumes about 1 ms before the "consume" function in the sink is called. That is enough to cause loss of data from the serial port when using async_read_until.

Lessons learned: Do not call any time consuming tasks in the handler function in async_read_until